# Varnish POST cache not working though PHP CURL, however, it seems to be working with TERMINAL CURL

Tags: php, apache, curl, varnish, varnish-vcl

[I referred this document](https://docs.varnish-software.com/tutorials/caching-post-requests/#introduction) to enable POST caching on Apache server. Service side scripting language used is PHP.

As mentioned I called the php file using

```
curl --data '{"maxresults":2000}' http://localhost/varnishoutput/varnishtest.php
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{"1":{"{\"maxresults\":2000}":""},"2":"NOO"}
```

The output was cached and any changes made in the **"varnishtest.php"**. Din't change the response for the **POST** value **"ABC"**. However, if the POST value was changed, the newly changed response was shown. Thus **POST cache** on Terminal end is working.

However, if I call the same URL from other PHP file using CURL. The output is not cached. Here is the PHP code that I used.

**varnishpost.php**

```
<?php
$data = array();
$data['maxresults'] = 2000;
$api = "http://localhost/varnishoutput/varnishtest.php";
$s = curl_init();

curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_URL,$api);
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
curl_setopt($s,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT,$data);

$response = curl_exec($s);
$header = curl_getinfo($s);
curl_close($s);

$dataArr = json_decode($response);
print_r($dataArr);
echo "\n\n";
print_r($header);
echo "\n\n";
echo $api. "\n\n";

?>
```

**varnishtest.php**

```
<?php

echo json_encode(array("1"=>$_POST,"2"=>"NOO"));
?>
```

**Output**

```
 stdClass Object
    (
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [maxresults] => 2000
            )

        [2] => NOO
    )
```

**Header Output**

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://localhost/varnishoutput/varnishtest.php
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 359
    [request_size] => 207
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.005651
    [namelookup_time] => 0.004235
    [connect_time] => 0.004385
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.004474
    [size_upload] => 149
    [size_download] => 37
    [speed_download] => 6547
    [speed_upload] => 26367
    [download_content_length] => 37
    [upload_content_length] => 149
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.00478
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => ::1
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 80
    [local_ip] => ::1
    [local_port] => 57130
    [request_header] => POST /varnishoutput/varnishtest.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 149
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------072b0f786662


)
```

The header output doesn't show any **"X-Varnish" value in header info**. Also, the Output changes every time the response file is changed for the same POST value. Thus post cache isn't working in this case.

**THE VCL FILE code is as follow:**

```
#
# This is an example VCL file for Varnish.
#
# It does not do anything by default, delegating control to the
# builtin VCL. The builtin VCL is called when there is no explicit
# return statement.
#
# See the VCL chapters in the Users Guide at https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/
# and http://varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExamples for more examples.

# Marker to tell the VCL compiler that this VCL has been adapted to the
# new 4.0 format.
vcl 4.0;
import std;
import bodyaccess;
# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "192.168.0.108";
    .port = "8080";
    .connect_timeout = 120s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 120s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 120s;
}
sub vcl_recv {
    unset req.http.X-Body-Len;
    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    # 
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc.

    # Do not cache these paths.
    if (req.url ~ "(/userInfo/|gm_internet_testing.php|/abc-wct/|/ren_api/|/book_api/|/eve_api/getEveScore.php|/iptoct_api/|/ct_api/.*\bweather\b|/rec_api/.*\bopennow\b)") {
        return (pass);
    }
# Replace the parameter &_= which is a random integer passed when jquery ajax cache is false
    if (req.url ~ "&_=[0-9]+$") {
        set req.url = regsub(req.url,"&_=[0-9]+$","");
    }
    if (req.method == "POST" ) {
        std.log("Will cache POST for: " + req.http.host + req.url);
        std.cache_req_body(500KB);
        set req.http.X-Body-Len = bodyaccess.len_req_body();
        if (req.http.X-Body-Len == "-1") {
            return(synth(400, "The request body size exceeds the limit"));
        }
        return (hash);
    }
# Handling to cache pages across browsers / devices
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
    set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
    } else if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
    } else {
    # unknown algorithm
        unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
    }
}

if (req.http.user-agent ~ "MSIE") {
    set req.http.user-agent = "MSIE";
} else {
    set req.http.user-agent = "Mozilla";
}

unset req.http.Cookie;
}

sub vcl_hash {
# To cache POST and PUT requests
    if (req.http.X-Body-Len) {
       bodyaccess.hash_req_body();
    } else {
       hash_data("");
    }
}
sub vcl_backend_fetch {
    if (bereq.http.X-Body-Len) {
        set bereq.method = "POST";
    }
}
sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    # 
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    # 
    # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.
}
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Can you please share your VCL file? Also, the document you're referring to is a Varnish Enterprise page. If you're a Varnish Enterprise user, and have an enterprise license, you're better of e-mailing Varnish Software support.

Comment: @ThijsFeryn I have updated the question, adding the code of VCL file. We are not a Varnish Enterprise user. Any help you could provide would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I notice a discrepancy between the *POST data* on the command line and the data in the PHP script.

The `--data '{"maxresults":2000}'` in your *cURL* request will actually send a *JSON object* as payload.

When I look at your PHP script, `$data['maxresults'] = 2000;` is just regular POST data, which is not the same.

Because you perform a `bodyaccess.hash_req_body();` in `vcl_hash`, the lookup hash will be different if the *POST body* is different. That's why you'll get a miss in your script.

#### JSON payload

If you want the same result, I'd advise you to set the *POST fields* as follows:

```
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($data));
```

### Regular POST fields

If you want to use regular *POST fields* instead, you can perform the following *cURL* call on the command line:

```
curl --data 'maxresults=2000' http://localhost/varnishoutput/varnishtest.php
```

And this is the change you need to make in your PHP file if you want to use pure *POST fields*:

```
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
```